# Limit LDAP Query for Security Group

Tags: security, permissions, active-directory

We have a few domain accounts that are used to do LDAP queries for various systems.  We don't want these accounts to be able to query all of the OUs in our AD.

- @ domain level we have given Authenticated Users Read access to all OUs.
- Created a Security group that these accounts are members of.
- Granted Security Group Read access to the three OUs where we have Users that they should be able to query.
- Issued Deny Full Control rights to all of the other OUs that contain Users.

One of the systems using an account is our Copiers.  A global search of the directory is still pulling up Users that exist within the OUs that have denys configured.

Not sure how this could be happening.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to have a deny on just the OU the objects are in. The permission needs to be a deny for:

- List Contents
- Read All Properties
- Read Permissions

And it needs to be applied for "This object and all descendant objects" on the OU in question.

Comment: When you configure security to be a Deny at Full Control level, it automatically checks ALL of the items within the list, which includes List Contents, Read All Properties, & Read Permissions.

We verified that the Deny permissions were pushed to all descendent objects, which includes the users that we're able to Lookup from the copier.

Comment: To be clear, we put the deny at the OU and verified that all subordinate OUs, Security Groups and Users under that OU received inherited deny permission.

Comment: If you go to the security tab for one of the users you don't want them to be able to view/query, then go to the effective permissions tab under advanced and enter in the account doing the query, what do the effective permissions show?

Comment: Thank you!  Found the issue.  Somehow, someone gave explicit read permissions for Authenticated Users.  Explicit permissions override inherited permissions, even if the inherited permissions include a Deny.